# Is there a way to get rid of the hyperlink from a bullet point but not the text in html?

Tags: html, css

I want the words from my list to remain hyperlinked but not the bullet points themselves.Or is this something that has to be solved with CSS?

I wrapped each link attribute in an a tag. This changes the color and click-ability of both the bullet point and the text. I only want the words to be a hyperlink.

```
 <ul>
     <a href="https.random.com" target="_blank"><li>Home</li></a>
     <a href="https.random.com" target="_blank"><li>About</li></a>
     <a href="https.random.com" target="_blank"><li>Contact</li></a>
     <a href="https.random.com" target="_blank"><li>Careers</li></a>

    </ul>
```

Comment: Please include a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: This is not even valid HTML syntax...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's easy if you think about it ..
You are using a list element inside a link but you can try using the link inside the list element

```
<ul>
  <li><a href="https.random.com" target="_blank">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="https.random.com" target="_blank">About</a></li>
  <li><a href="https.random.com" target="_blank">Contact</a></li>
  <li><a href="https.random.com" target="_blank">Careers</a></li>
</ul>
```